# How to have unique value for a key while storing in firestore field as a list

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, hashmap

I am storing a list of hashmaps under a field "reacts",using this code below

```
 val emoji = HashMap<String, Long>()
        emoji[_uid] = Type
        repository.getPostReference(postId).update("reacts", FieldValue.arrayUnion(emoji))
```

and it is getting stored like below,is there any way i can ensure their is only one value for a key?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way i can ensure their is only one value for a key?

Not with `arrayUnion()`: As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array), "`arrayUnion()` adds elements to an array **but only elements not already present**".

Since you are storing HashMaps in the Array, the two elements are not considered equivalent. (The keys are similar but not the values).

You will need to read the Array in your front-end, update it and write it back to the database.

Comment: If by "update value of an existing key" you mean update an element of the Array at a specific position, you will need to read the entire Array in your front-end, update it and write it back to the database.